# Как подключить внешний js-файл в Yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, cdn

Пытаюсь в `Yii2` подключить js-файл, доступный через `Content Delivery Network`, но получаю ошибку `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`.

Прошу подсказать, что я делаю неправильно, и как это исправить. Код подключения:

```
<?php $this->registerJs('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@5.1.0/dist/amplitude.js"></script>', $this::POS_READY); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rejisterJs` используется для другого. Вы можете добавить посторонний скрипт, например, с помощью AssetBundle - стандартно идет один, вроде как AppAsset называется.

`public $js = ['https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@5.1.0/dist/amplitude.js']`

[документация, более детально](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets)

Comment: спасибо! таким образом можно подключить более чем один файл?

Comment: Да. Почитайте о структуре AppAsset. Если у вас стандартный шаблон то в этом файле уже должны быть подключены файлы. Там в массив можно добавлять сколько угодно скриптов.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать метод registerJs(), то во внутрь надо писать js код в строках т.е.

```
this->registerJs("alert('hello world!')");
```

Если хотите подключить файл, то для этого есть метод registerJsFile

```
$this->registerJsFile("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/amplitudejs@5.1.0/dist/amplitude.js", ['position' => $this::POS_HEAD]);
```

Подробности [тут](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts)